# problem with function getBaseUrl() in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

i have `BaseUrl` class in this path `application\views\helpers`

```
class Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl {
    function baseUrl ()
    {
        $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        return $fc->getBaseUrl();
    }
}
```

but in my views when i use

```
echo $this->baseUrl();
```

its `null`;

someone could help ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already a View-Helper for BaseURL : `class Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract`

I think you have problem with the default ; try to rename your `Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl` or try to use the default one.

Comment: zend_framework version is  1.11 , i typed wrong above comment i used $vie= new Zend_View_Helper_BaseUrl(); echo $vie->getBaseUrl(); and its null

Comment: What if you use `echo $this->baseUrl();` in your view ?

Comment: That can be normal if your DocumentRoot is "/" ;  can you use an other DocumentRoot, like "/something". The test will print that. Note that inn you base URL, you never had the domain, only the URI to the current script. You know